# Make Chart.js canvas responsive inside the resizeable div

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, charts, chart.js

I would like to create a container which would have Chart.js chart inside itself, but the trick it that the chart has to stay responsive relative to its parent and not only to the viewport - since the parent should be resizeable… How could I make it "aware" so it stretches correctly..? I have tried several ways but none have worked..here's the pen with the example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeYWNw

```
.container {
  width: 100%;      
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Thanks a lot for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `.container` to have:

```
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

If you want the chart to fit itself to the `div` set `maintainAspectRatio: false`.

Here's a working example:

```js
let myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('chart'), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Series1',
        data: [1, 10, 6]
      }]
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false
    }
  }
);
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I don't get your question correctly, but deleting the max-width should do the trick...

Comment: unfortunately no..div should be resizeable and the chart within it should adapt to the changed width

Comment: The div is resizable until the max-width of 700px. That's the whole idea of a max-width.... otherwise you will have to clarify your question (or wait for other answers) ;-)

Comment: changed to 100%

Comment: That's better ;-) Does that answer your question? - Although, in many cases auto may be preferred instead of 100%. But in this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: nope...i'm trying to get that div with the border to be resizeable, and content within it responsive